# Git Bash isn't handling my print statements and raw_inputs in order python 2.7.18

Tags: python

I'm very new to programming and have just picked up "Learn Python the Hard Way", and have run into an issue that I'm not quite sure how to phrase. Whenever I try to run a file with a `raw_input`, the terminal seems to completely ignore any `print` statements until every `raw_input` is filled and then just spits them all out at the end.

This is the code the book wants me to use:

```
print "How old are you?",
age = raw_input()
print "How tall are you?",
height = raw_input()
print "How much do you weigh?",
weight = raw_input()

print "So, you're %r old, %r tall and %r heavy." % (
    age, height, weight)
```

But whenever I try and run this in Git Bash I get 3 blank input boxes with no text, and after I fill out all 3 it spits out:

> How old are you? How tall are you? How much do you weigh? So, you're '18' old, '6 feet' tall and '180 lbs' heavy.

If i use an [online python 2 editor](https://repl.it/languages/Python) I get the expected result: (minus the quotations around each line, I just added those here to show what was displayed)

```
"How old are you? 18"
"How tall are you? 6 feet"
"How much do you weigh? 180 lbs"
"So, you're '18' old, '6 feet' tall and '180 lbs' heavy"
```

But on my own computer it breaks every time. Has anyone else ever experienced something similar to this? If so how did you fix it?

Comment: Don't use python 2.7, use python 3

Comment: There's a more up-to-date version of the book with Python 3 syntax. [Learn Python 3 the Hard Way](https://www.amazon.com.au/Learn-Python-Hard-Way-Introduction/dp/0134692888)

Answer (score 0):

```
age = input("How old are you?").strip()
height = input("How tall are you?").strip()
weight = input("How much do you weigh?").strip()

print("So, you're %r old, %r tall and %r heavy." % (age, height, weight))
```

Output:

```
How tall are you? 6 feet
How much do you weigh? 180 lbs
So, you're '18' old, '6 feet' tall and '180 lbs' heavy.
```